# Display 'NULL' instead of empty row in pl/sql function

Tags: oracle, plsql

Got the following pl/sql function that extracts numbers from the string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION extract_number (
in_number VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
RETURN regexp_replace(in_number, '[^[:digit:]]', '');
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Need to put NULL where no numeric value was found (instead of just empty row). Example:

Got a table:

```
create table tab2 (val varchar2(100));
insert into tab2 (val) values ('2133jdhfjshd4');
insert into tab2 (val) values ('afafaf');
insert into tab2 (val) values ('skdjfj6787887hhh');
insert into tab2 (val) values ('324824898');
insert into tab2 (val) values ('4jh4jhh4');
commit;
```

This is an output from function:

```
          21334

        6787887
      324824898
            444
```

On the second row I need 'NULL' to be placed.

NO_DATA_FOUND not working. Please advise what should I do?

Comment: Warning: don't mess with data types! If the return value is `NULL`, why do you want to replace that with a four-letter string? As you saw already, using one of the proposed solutions, you will have to change the data type of the return - from number to varchar2. Presumably a function like this would be used to extract numbers from strings, to be used in further computations - **as numbers**. Change the function to return varchar2 instead, and a lot of other things will break. If you need to display "NULL" on reports, do it in the reporting layer, not in the function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the regexp_replace in NVL():

```
NVL(regexp_replace(in_number, '[^[:digit:]]', ''), 'NULL');
```

If NULL is returned by regexp_replace(), return the string 'NULL'.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions110.htm#SQLRF00684)

Comment: worked after replaced RETURN NUMBER in function to RETURN VARCHAR2

Answer (score 0):

In sqlplus you can use this `set null 'null'`. And this is only for presentation.

I see few problem with your function.

1. `regexp_replace` never throws no_data_found exception
2. The result of regexp_replace is always varchar2 or `null` and oracle has to do the implicit conversion to the number.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of  `NO_DATA_FOUND` . However you can raise it anyway..

```
CREATE FUNCTION extract_number (in_number VARCHAR2)
       RETURN NUMBER
    IS
       v_return   NUMBER (10);
    BEGIN
       v_return := REGEXP_REPLACE (in_number, '[^[:digit:]]', '');

       IF v_return IS NULL
       THEN
          RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
       END IF;

       RETURN v_return;
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
       THEN
          RETURN NULL;
    END;
```